# Как добавить в БД строку извне с помощью post-запроса?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Во время создания новой строки БД и отправки post-запроса через метод create создается authenticity_token, который исключает возможность отправки post-запросов извне. Как убрать authenticity_token?

Comment: Смотрю я на ваши вопросы и думаю, а зачем вам вообще Ruby on Rails? Может, с [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) вам будет проще? Ну, для начала. Если уж вы хотите разобрать простые случаи. `authenticity_token` убрать несложно, как и начать использовать его. Просто похоже, что ваши цели сильно отличаются от того, для чего нужен Rails.

Comment: Я создаю самое обычное веб-приложение. Разве Rails не для этого?

Comment: Rails по умолчанию поставляется с целой пачкой удобств и средств для обеспечения безопасности, совместимости и других полезных для типичного веб-приложения качеств. `authenticity_token` в том числе. Он не без причины включен по умолчанию. Если вам нужен максимум контроля и много отклонений от настроек по умолчанию, вы достаточно много времени можете потратить, отвинчивая от Rails винтик за винтиком. И в этом случае вам стоит рассмотреть другие инструменты. Если же у вас правда "самое обычное веб-приложение", то да, Rails вам поможет.

Comment: Я собираюсь создать веб-приложение, которое работает с базой данных на сервере. Оно должно ловить http-запросы от android-приложения и выполнять различные действия над бд, будь то удаление, добавление, редактирование и т.д.

Comment: Ны, это не веб-приложение, это веб-API (предназначенный не для непосредственно пользователей, а для приложений). В пятой версии у Rails какой-то особенный режим для конструирования таких появился, который отключает много ненужных вещей.

Comment: Что за режим и как включить?

Comment: См. [гайды](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html). Лично с этим не работал.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо, что направили